# Total number of guesses when it has found the target in Binary seach

Tags: javascript, search, binary, counting

**Here is the request**
To help visualize how long the search takes, add a println() statement that displays the total number of guesses it takes to find the result.

Your function should only print the total number of guesses when it has found the target. Your function shouldn't be printing the number of guesses every loop.

Note: A binary search for the target value 41 on the array primes requires 1 guess.

**My code**

```js
var doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
 var min = 0;
 var max = array.length - 1;
    var guess;
    var count = 0;
    while(min <= max) {
        guess = Math.floor((max + min)/2);
        count ++;
        if(array[guess] === targetValue) {
            println(guess);
            println(count ++);
            return guess;
        }
        //again
        else if (targetValue < array[guess]){
        max = guess - 1;
        } 
        else {
        min = guess + 1;
        }
    }
    
 return -1;
};

var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
  41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

var result = doSearch(primes, 73);
println("Found prime at index " + result);

Program.assertEqual(doSearch(primes, 73), 20);
```

**Still wrong withtis notify** 
It looks like you are incrementing the number of guesses in each clause. Try incrementing the number of guesses in just one place.

What did I wrong?

Comment: You have count++ in two places. There's no need for the ++ again after the value is found.

Comment: You should not have incremented `count` inside the `println` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Full answer

var doSearch = function(array, targetValue) {
    var min = 0;
    var max = array.length - 1;
    var guess;
    var count = 0;
    while (max >= min) {
        guess = Math.floor((max + min)/2);
        count++;
        if (array[guess] === targetValue) {
            println(guess);
            println(count);
            return guess;
        
        }
        else if (array[guess] < targetValue) {
            min = guess + 1;
            println(array[guess]);
        }
        else {
            max = guess - 1;
            println(array[guess]);
        }
    }
            


    return -1;
};

var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
    41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

var result = doSearch(primes, 73);
println("Found prime at index " + result);

Program.assertEqual(doSearch(primes, 73), 20);
```

Comment: You should also add some additional information or explanation about the answer.